# QGIS 2.8 topological editing creating vertices

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8

When using the node tool with topological editing enabled on a group of multiple lines, double clicking sometimes doesn't create new vertices. Instead, the line segment gets selected. When this happens, the only solution is to select a different set of lines or a different tool and then return with the node tool to the set of lines I'm currently trying to edit. The issue seems to be aggravated by larger numbers of lines (it doesn't happen at all when editing a single line).

The sequence I run into is I start to edit a group of lines - the first double-click creates a new vertex but subsequent double-clicks result in the impasse and I have to change focus or tools to reset it.

How can I continue to create new vertices by double-clicking?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the source of the problem, but the issue is less severe for me if I turn off OTF and use 'Check Geometry Validity...'. If you could dropbox your layer and your .qgs file I could troubleshoot it.

Comment: An example layer is at http://gtfs.bigbluebus.com/

scroll to the bottom of the page and download "shapes" (easiest would be "shapes.zip" at the very bottom because it contains a shapefile which would be editable without conversion)

Easiest basemap to use would be openlayers Google Streets.

This layer contains bus route traces. Multiple routes share the same streets. We use QGIS to align the route data to Google Maps. When topological editing is enabled so that you're moving all the routes sharing the same street the problem described above is a regular occurrence.